# How to make the cell containing the radio button as ActiveCell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with different records.
What I want: A radio button to the left of each record. When I click the radio button, the corresponding cells to the right of it are selected and copied.

Where's the problem:
Identifying ActiveCell. I can't make the cell containing the radio button as the ActiveCell. Upon clicking the radio button, Excel considers the last cell that I clicked as ActiveCell and starts copying relative to that. I want selection relative to the cell containing the radio button.

I would appreciate if someone could write the macro to make the cell containing the radio button as ActiveCell. I inserted the radio button from Developer>Insert>Form Controls.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: hi. to get the row try ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TopLeftCell` or `BottomRightCell` to get the position of the Option Button

```
Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Dim rdioButton As OptionButton

    Set rdioButton = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).DrawingObject

    Debug.Print "TopLeft", rdioButton.TopLeftCell.Address
    Debug.Print "BottomRight", rdioButton.BottomRightCell.Address

    rdioButton.TopLeftCell.Select
    Debug.Print "ActiveCell", ActiveCell.Address

End Sub
```

To view the Immediate Window press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in the `VBA` editor to see the output of the `Debug` statements above or navigate to it by View->Immediate Window